# Similar command to linux tree command in adb shell

Tags: android, linux, adb

I want to list all files and folders of music directory of android mobile. Where I am using

```
ls -l -R /sdcard/music
```

It gives all files and folders but not in a proper way.

Any one tell me adb shell command that displays files and folders hierarchy of a directory like "tree" linux command.

Answer (score 30):

I don't know if you still looking for this, but I believe this command can help you (works on adb as well):

```
find . -print | sort | sed 's;[^/]*/;|---;g;s;---|; |;g'
```

It prints a directory tree (both folders and files) in a more readable way than

```
ls -l -R
```

If you want just a folder tree, you can use this one:

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install busybox for android, it will add many well known linux tools to your phone.
You need a rooted phone for installing busybox.

Check it out here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=fr